# iOS 16 with broken UIDatepicker .inline

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, picker

Any one notice that app with date picker with style .inline freeze and crash ?

I used below code at my existing app at Appstore

```
 if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        }else {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .automatic
        }
```

For working .inline with iOS16 I need to force add this condition

```
 if #available(iOS 16, *) {
                datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
            }else {
                datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
            }
```

**Having result:**

[image]